# Criptografar uma string em python

Tags: python, criptografia

Gostaria de saber se existe algum algoritmo de criptografia onde é possivel escolher qual a chave ou parte dela que sera usada para criptografar/descriptografar a mensagem

Um exemplo:

```
mensagem = 'string qualquer'

chave = 'chave escolhida'

mensagem_encriptada = encrypt(mensagem, key = chave)

print(mensagem_encriptada)

mensagem_recuperada = decrypt(mensagem_encriptada, key = chave)

print(mensagem_recuperada)
```

Saida esperada seria essa:

(uma string qualquer como dfg1tre*vf2d3jnh&&^/vfdfhgf34@@cfr%ws76z!)
string qualquer

Comment: Veja se esta [lib](https://pypi.org/project/cryptocode/) te ajuda

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Depende da criptografia  simétrica ou assimétrica.

Há bibliotecas que auxiliam a criar uma boa criptografia  usando AES e a RSA.

um simples exemplo usando a função xor:
Quanto maior a chave mais segura sera, quanto menor  mais fácil sera para identificar a mensagem

```
import string
import random


chave = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits + '^!\$%&/()=?{[]}+~#-_.:,;<>|\\') for _ in range(0, 1024))


print(chave)

mensagem = 'python'

print("Msg: " + mensagem + '\n')




def str_xor(s1, s2):
    return "".join([chr(ord(c1) ^ ord(c2)) for (c1, c2) in zip(s1,s2)])



secreta = str_xor(mensagem, chave)

print("Mensagem secreta :"+secreta + "\n")

recuperando_mensagem_secreta = str_xor(secreta, chave)
print("Mensagem descriptografada " + "\n" + recuperando_mensagem_secreta + "\n")
```

A cada vez que o código for iniciado uma nova criptografia sera criada

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar alguma biblioteca para fazer a criptografia. Tem várias bibliotecas, como a [pycrypto](https://pypi.org/project/pycrypto/), [cryptocode](https://pypi.org/project/cryptocode/) e etc. Tem dezenas de bibliotecas por aí.
Um exemplo simples desse seu mesmo programinha usando a biblioteca cryptocode:

```
import cryptocode

chave = "423338233093093"
mensagem = "Esta eh a minha mensagem! :)"

MensagemCriptografada = cryptocode.encrypt(mensagem, chave)
print("Sua mensagem criptografada: " + MensagemCriptografada)

MensagemDescriptografada = cryptocode.decrypt(MensagemCriptografada, chave)
print("Sua mensagem descriptografada: " + MensagemDescriptografada)
```

A saída será:

> Sua mensagem criptografada: gSjdIssy9DOYfPnACctSaoNn4/VcTRzlLYh4PQ==*dv9iN+Uwsad+v8QMBUgF7A==*4G2FKJ2n+WJxwak9LpyaWw==*lvCp3brLC0nJVd1g4lf3Vg==
> Sua mensagem descriptografada: Esta eh a minha mensagem! :)